# Can I use Hibernate Envers with Eclipse Link?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I need to audit my application, I don't know if it is possible to mix the Hibernate and Eclipse Link implementation.
If it is not possible what Envers alternatives do I have?

Comment: Do you need hibernate envers or just auditing? https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Auditing

Comment: I want to use Envers because I want to save the user who made the modifications on the history table. Envers let me do that using a custom "revision entity"

Comment: If you looked at the link, it also records the user making the change. So its up to you, what are you more tied to?  The docs seem to suggest Envers is a Hibernate JPA extension - you can try to make it work in EclipseLink, but I doubt you'll be successful

Comment: Thank you Chris. I will try., but now I have the problem in how to "inject" the user on the audit object. I have a JSF application with programatically security, saving the user on the Session object

Comment: Hey henry, can you update us- did you used JPA auditing or JPA history? was it Javers or Audit4j ? Thanks